# Unable to install SQL Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I am trying to install a new instance of SQL server 2012 on my server, I get the following error message when I try to run the iso (before any gui appears):

> The operating system on this computer does not meet the minimum requirements  for SQL Server 2012. For Windows Vista or Server 2008 operating systems, Service Pack 2 or later is required. For Windows 7 or Windows Serer 2008 R2, Service Pack 1 or later is required. For more information, see Hardware and Software Requirements for installing SQL Server 2012 at:
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=195092

The server is virtual, running under hyper-v with 4GB static ram, and 2 processor cores. The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 x64. Every drive has more than 20GB RAM. I have rebooted the server to see if that changes the situation and it doesn't.

As for the other installation requirements:

- .net 3.5.1 feature is installed
- Powershell 2.0 is installed

The strangest part in all of this, is that the server already has instances of SQL Server 2012 running. These instances were installed using the same iso that is being used to attempt this new install.

Comment: do you have visual C runtime 2010 installed? that's a common error caused by it missing

Comment: Are you installing SQL 2012 or SQL 2012 Express?

Comment: repairing microsoft .net 4.0 can be the problem solver; if you run out of options, you can also use another local account to install it, then relog into your current account.

Comment: I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. Visual C++ 2010 as well as a full visual studio is installed on the server. The existing SQL Server 2012 instances are all working correctly. I am going to repair .net 4.0 now.

Comment: Logging in as a different user solved the problem (strangely). It still doesn't work with my old user account, but as long as I can install a new instance I'm happy. If you put this down as an answer I will mark as solution.

Comment: @LoganBissonnette good to know i was able to help you somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As asked by the QA, i'm adding my comment as an answer:

Repairing microsoft .net 4.0 can be the problem solver; if you run out of options, you can also use another local account to install it, then relog into your current account.

Comment: How does .net 4.0 get broken in the first place that it needs repaired?  How would you ever guess that the .net Framework is broken, to even consider repairing it?

Comment: from experience. had the same issue with several other computers; this step solved the problem.